# How to get certain parts of JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this JSON data:

```
[{"code":"ABC","quantity":8,"userId":"123","isLast":false},{"code":"ABE","quantity":8,"userId":"1222","isLast":false},
{"code":"ABD","quantity":8,"userId":"023","isLast":true}]
```

is it possible to get the sum of all the `quantity` with the value?

expected result:

```
24
```

Comment: Yes. it is possible.

Comment: Fix the quote characters, parse as JSON then map the array to extract quantities

Comment: you should make your question more clear for example, you can search for the total of quantity or store the quantity in an array and so on. also don't forget to attach your code first (what you have tried) before asking

Comment: thank you for the replies. i wasn't sure how to start which is why i posted this question. i can try using split but i'm not sure which separator can i use to get all the quantities

Comment: would be great if the person who closed this question can open it back so i can edit it.

Comment: @tiredqa_18 it doesn't need to be open, you as the author can always edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appear to be a JSON, the first thing you want to do is convert it into an object. From there you can iterate through the array and pull any information you need:

```js
const string = `[{"code":"ABC","quantity":8,"userId":"123","isLast":false},{"code":"ABE","quantity":7,"userId":"1222","isLast":false},
{"code":"ABD","quantity":9,"userId":"023","isLast":true}]`;

// convert it into an object
const obj = JSON.parse(string);

// get array of quantity values
const quantity = obj.map(a => a.quantity);
console.log("quantity array:", quantity);

// get sum of quantity values
const quantitySum = obj.reduce((a,b) => (a.quantity === undefined ? a : a.quantity) + b.quantity);
console.log("Sum:", quantitySum);
```

Answer (score 1):

First store your data into a variable:

```
const data = [
    {“code”:“ABC",“quantity”:8,“userId”:“123",“isLast”:false},
    {“code”:“ABE",“quantity”:8,“userId”:“1222",“isLast”:false},
    {“code”:“ABD",“quantity”:8,“userId”:“023",“isLast”:true}
]
```

If you want to store all `quantity` items inside an array, you can use map function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```
const array = data.map(item => item['quantity'])
// array = [ 8, 8, 8 ]
```

If you want to get the sum of all `quantity` items, you can use forEach function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```
let sum = 0
sum = data.forEach(item => sum += item)
// sum = 8 + 8 + 8 = 24
```

Comment: thanks Jabal. I wasn't really sure how to start/approach this so i appreciate this very much.